# Running several Jest tests when spying the same prototype function

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, spyon

I have some code similar to this:

```
class A {
    f1() { }
}
function f2() {
    const a = new A();
    a.f1();
}
test('test1', async () => {
    const spy_f1 = jest.spyOn(A.prototype, "f1");
    f2();
    console.log("In test1", spy_f1.mock.calls);
});
test('test2', async () => {
    const spy_f1 = jest.spyOn(A.prototype, "f1");
    f2();
    console.log("In test2", spy_f1.mock.calls);
});
```

I want to test how many times and with which arguments function `f2` calls function `f1`.
To do that I would like to spy function `f1`. Though, for that, I need the object on which `f1` is applied, and that object is local to function `f2`. So, I cannot.

Another possibility is to spy on the object `A.prototype`. It works if I run only `test1` or only `test2`. But if I run both, the two tests are not independent on each other. For `test2`, it appears that `f1` is called twice.

Other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to keep in different test files all the tests spying on the same prototype.